# QGIS Raster calculator getting invalid expression

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, expression

I'm trying to use the Raster Calculator tool in QGIS 3.10 Coruna on a slope map to isolate areas between 20 and 40 degrees of slope using the formula `''Raster1'' = > 20 AND < = 40`. I keep getting 'invalid expression'.

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Correct syntax is: `"Raster1@1" >= 20 AND  "Raster1@1" <= 40`

Your expression has the following errors:

1. You must repeat the raster layer after the `AND`.
2. Use double quotes `"` insted of two single quotes `'` for the name of the raster.
3. You must combine the name of the raster layer with `@` and the number of the band - here: `1`.

To avoid errors 2 and 3, select the raster band name from the list of available raster bands. You find it in the upper left part of the raster calculator dialog. Double click a name to add it to the Raster calculator expression field to be sure it has the correct syntax.